# Very simple probability problem

Tags: probability

There is a lightbulb and a button before a person. When a person pushes the button, lightbulb will light up for a moment with the probability of 1%. After the participant has pushed the button $ n $ times, what is the probability of him seeing the lightbulb light up *at least* once? This problem was given to me, complete layman, by my mathematician friend. He said it is quite easy to solve, but after hours of thinking I have no idea where to start. What is the answer to this problem and, what's more important, why is it the way it is?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good point to start in most probability problem where you get stuck: what is the probability that you *never* sees the light after $n$ pushes ?

To get you started: on one push, you have 99%=$\frac{99}{100}$ probability of not seeing it.
After two pushes, $(\frac{99}{100})^2$. I let you finish...

Comment: Obviously, in general the probability of never seeing the lightbulb light up after $ n $ trials should be $(0.99)^n$. So is the probability in question $1-(0.99)^n $?

Comment: yes that's it! You can try to compute for instance after how many tries you go above 50% chance.

Comment: The answer is actually... 69. I'm serious lol